# Install database with apk and keep it up to date with a server

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I would like to integrate into my app a ready-made SQLite database, so that the most urgent data is available right at the first opening of the app.
Then, if a newer version of the database is available, you should be asked if you want to update it.

Comment: OK, great. What are you stuck on, in particular?

Comment: I do not know which libraries I should use. And how I should manage the whole thing then. I would be satisfied with example code, e.g. how to check if a newer version of the database is available and how it works with the download, on which path I should download then and how I can read the database, etc.

Comment: That is a very broad question, to which a book could be written as an answer. `:-)` I guess this post will be put on hold for that reason, so I would urge you to narrow it down. Do as much independent research as you can, and add that to the post.

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do for this is get the backend (the server that sends the updates) to send a time at the start of the request. When you enter the app the first time update the SQL lite tables and save the time in shared prefs. Then every time they open the app compare the saved time to the time being sent from the database if it has changed that means you have a update ready to send and you can notify the user.

If you are sending a json request from the DB you would just need a tag like this at the start of the data to check:

```
 "last_update": 1526340499514
```